# Kafka producer: send avro as array[byte] without schema

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to setup a simple kafka stack in local and I am at the point where I need to create a toy Producer. This: https://lombardo-chcg.github.io/tools/2017/09/29/kafka-avro-producer-in-scala.html (see below for the piece of code I'm interested in) is almost exactly what I want except:

Here the producer sends a GenericData.Record object, so the whole schema is sent and it doesn't leverage the schema registry. I want to send an Array[Byte] with the first few bytes being the id of the schema and the following bytes being the data, without the schema (or so I think it is the optimal way to do it)

The piece of code I am talking about:

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

case class User(name: String, favoriteNumber: Int, favoriteColor: String)

class AvroProducer {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  val kafkaBootstrapServer = sys.env("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER")
  val schemaRegistryUrl = sys.env("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL")

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServer)
  props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)
  props.put("key.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("acks", "1")

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, GenericData.Record](props)
  val schemaParser = new Parser

  val key = "key1"
  val valueSchemaJson =
  s"""
    {
      "namespace": "com.avro.junkie",
      "type": "record",
      "name": "User2",
      "fields": [
        {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "favoriteNumber",  "type": "int"},
        {"name": "favoriteColor", "type": "string"}
      ]
    }
  """
  val valueSchemaAvro = schemaParser.parse(valueSchemaJson)
  val avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(valueSchemaAvro)

  val mary = new User("Mary", 840, "Green")
  avroRecord.put("name", mary.name)
  avroRecord.put("favoriteNumber", mary.favoriteNumber)
  avroRecord.put("favoriteColor", mary.favoriteColor)

  def start = {
    try {
      val record = new ProducerRecord("users", key, avroRecord)
      val ack = producer.send(record).get()
      // grabbing the ack and logging for visibility
      logger.info(s"${ack.toString} written to partition ${ack.partition.toString}")
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable => logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
    }
  }
}
```

Problem(s):

- I don't know how to retrieve the id of the schema from schema-registry
- I don't know how to send only the data without the schema + the id as Array[Byte]

I know how to write the whole avro to Array[Byte]:

```
    val writer = new SpecificDatumWriter[GenericData.Record](valueSchemaAvro)
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val encoder = EncoderFactory.get.binaryEncoder(out, null)
    writer.write(avroRecord, encoder) // but here I am also writing the schema, right?
    encoder.flush
    out.close
    out.toByteArray
```

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code *does* use the Schema Registry, and computes an ID + replaces the schema in the byte array for you within `KafkaAvroSerializer`

If you want to bypass the Schema Registry, use `ByteArraySerializer` and send the result of `out.toByteArray` in the second code block to the producer.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make things clear for me, if I bypass the schema-registry here at the producer level, I don’t even need to specify the schema registry url in the properties? But in this case I am really sending the schema in each message. So the cleverer way to do is by using the kafkaAvroSerializer.

Comment: You can keep the `props.put("schema.registry.url`, but it would not be used if you use the built-in Kafka serializers. The main benefit that the registry provides  is the ability to run backwards-compatibility checks against your schema, but the reduced network usage is also nice, if you have a large schema and many messages to send